# SQL: Find max rows in calculated fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find max rows in database. In my sample query it returns something like this:

[image: executed query]

But I want only rows with value "110".
We can't use `having` because max value isn't always "110". It can be "100" or "90" or...

It's my sql query:

```
select q.id,q.question,
if(isnull(date),'1970-01-01 00:00:00',date)date, if(qimg='','',concat(''))qimg,
case concat(if(isnull(last),'n',last),
if(isnull(plast) or plast='','n',plast),
if(isnull(pplast)or pplast='','n',pplast))
when 'www' then '110' 
when 'wwr' then '110' 
when 'wwe' then '110' 
when 'wwn' then '110' 
when 'wrw' then '110' 
when 'wrr' then '110' 
when 'wre' then '110' 
when 'wrn' then '110' 
when 'wew' then '110' 
when 'wer' then '110' 
when 'wee' then '110' 
when 'wen' then '110' 
when 'wnn' then '110' 
when 'rww' then '110' 
when 'rwr' then '90' 
when 'rwe' then '90' 
when 'rwn' then '100' 
when 'rrw' then '75' 
when 'rrr' then '40' 
when 'rre' then '40' 
when 'rrn' then '50' 
when 'rew' then '60' 
when 'rer' then '25' 
when 'ree' then '25' 
when 'ren' then '35' 
when 'rnn' then '65' 
when 'eww' then '100' 
when 'ewr' then '65' 
when 'ewe' then '65' 
when 'ewn' then '75' 
when 'erw' then '50' 
when 'err' then '15' 
when 'ere' then '15' 
when 'ern' then '25' 
when 'eew' then '35' 
when 'eer' then '10' 
when 'eee' then '10' 
when 'een' then '10' 
when 'enn' then '40' 
when 'nnn' then '110' end point 
from question q left join answer a on q.id=qid and a.user_id=1 
where subject=2 and level<=3 order by date,id
```

Thanks for any help?!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please consider giving a couple of examples - data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If the condition you want is "exactly 110", then you would need to replicate that huge `case` clause in your `where`, like

```
where case all-that-stuff end = 110
```

**but**

such an enormous list suggests that there might be a problem in your model; I would consider saving those pairs in a table, which you can then join in your existing query.

```
CODE   VALUE
------------
'www'  '110' 
'wwr'  '110' 
'wwe'  '110' 
'wwn'  '110' 
...

select  q.id,q.question,
        if(isnull(date), '1970-01-01 00:00:00', date) date,
        if(qimg='', '', concat('')) qimg,
        p.value point 
from    question q
left join answer a
on      q.id=qid and a.user_id=1 
join    newtable p
on      concat(if(isnull(last),'n',last),
               if(isnull(plast) or plast='','n',plast),
               if(isnull(pplast)or pplast='','n',pplast)) = p.code
where   subject=2 and level<=3 and p.value = 110
order by date,id
```

**Edit**

If you always want to filter the rows with maximum 'point' value, then I would recommend even more placing that data in a table, or in a view if the calculation is continuous.

You would end up with something like

```
select  q.id,q.question,
        if(isnull(date), '1970-01-01 00:00:00', date) date,
        if(qimg='', '', concat('')) qimg,
        p.value point 
from    question q
left join answer a
on      q.id=qid and a.user_id=1 
join    newtable p
on      concat(if(isnull(last),'n',last),
               if(isnull(plast) or plast='','n',plast),
               if(isnull(pplast)or pplast='','n',pplast)) = p.code
where   subject=2 and
        level<=3 and
        p.value = (select max(p.value) from newtable)
order by date,id
```

If having a separate table is not possible whatsoever, you would have to replace every occurrence of `newtable` with that huge `case` you wrote.

Comment: point filed is calculate field and i want rows with max point some time max point is 85 some time 110 some time 95 and ... max is not always 110

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the requirement. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an inline view?

```
SELECT * FROM (your_query) temp 
WHERE Point = (SELECT MAX(Point) from (your_query) temp2)
```

Comment: What do you mean? Is this a parameter? Then use a parameter instead of the literal 110.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't work because of the data type, I added quotes.

Comment: I think he meant that he wants (in this case) records that match `Point = '110'`, but he doesn't know that it is '110', so you would have to modify your SQL and calculate that '110' by using `MAX()` or sth like that.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.

Comment: i use max() from having for get rows with max point                             having point=max(point) bot max() not work corectly

Comment: I updated my answer, but you might have a problem with the data type: 100 > 90, but '100' < '90'. But this can be fixed.